# Frequency Capping

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Is there a way I can add frequency check for every email step? Check to see if the contact received an email in the last 24 hours, if not they move to next email touchpoint in the journey and if they do they wait 24 hours and go through the frequency check again before moving forward to next touchpoint?

Comment: Maybe you can do that with the SendLog dataextension and journey builder. When you would do a count per subscriberid / key and with a where clause like `b.EventDate>dateadd(d,-1,getdate())` which you automate before the journey send and attach it to the contact model. Then you could filter or decision split based on that criteria.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an out of the box solution, you would have to build a custom solution.

The custom solution I usually use is to:

1. Create a Data Extension (Sent DE) that holds all the subkeys of each subscriber that was sent to in past 24 hours.
2. Do a SQL query to another DE (Master DE) that contains all the subkeys of those in your journey that fills in a column named 'Capped' with 1 if on the Sent DE or 0 if not there.
3. Make sure your Master DE is attached to your Contact Model in the Journey
4. Put a split prior to each send that if Capped = 0 then move to send, else push them to a 24 hr wait period.
5. Make sure to set your queries inside a scheduled automation that will always run prior to your journey's send.